# Prove that if a function is both monotone and even, the function is a constant function

Tags: functions, even-and-odd-functions

So we would have $f(x) = f(-x)$ and $f$ can either be ascending or descending.

My approach to the problem  would be by Reduction To Absurdity. I would start off by saying that: "Suppose there actually is a function $f$ that meets those 2 requirements and is not constant". To make things easier I'd probably make a choice and say we're working with an increasing function.
We then take two values $x > y > 0$ therefore $f(x) \geq f(y)$ due to the function being increasing.
$-x < -y < 0$ is a pretty obvious deduction => $f(-x) \leq f(-y)$. But the function is even therefore: $f(-x) = f(x)$ and $f(-y) = f(y)$. Due to the inequality mentioned a bit earlier, we would have:
$f(x) \geq f(y)$ and $f(x) \leq f(y)$ therefore $f(x) = f(y)$.

Am I on the right track? These were my ideas so far.

Answer (score 2):

There is not need to mention $0$. Suppose that $f$ is increasing. If $f$ is not constant, then there are two numbers $x$ and $y$ with $x\ne y$ and $f(x)<f(y)$. Suppose that $x<y$. Then $-y<-x$ and$$f(-y)=f(y)>f(x)=f(-x).$$But this is impossible, since $f$ is increasing and $-y<-x$. If $x>y$ or if $f$ is decreasing, the argument is similar.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

Let $ x>0$.

then if $ f $ is for example, increasing,

$$f(-x)\le f(0)\le f(x)$$

or

$$f(x)=f(0)$$